# number of additive partition

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions, experimental-mathematics

I have a question related with  number of additive partition or method similar like this:
  $$p(5)=1+4=2+3=1+1+1+1+1=1+1+1+2=1+2+2=1+1+3$$

> For a given  number $n$,if we are trying to calculate number of additive partition of $p(n\cdot k)$  where  $k$ is some integer,or   $p(n+a+c)$ ,  $a,c \in \mathbb Z$,   is there commutative rules  or  something similar to calculate  number of partition of sum of some numbers?or  number of partition of   some number multiplied by another number?
>   For example like this   $$p(n+k)\overset{?}{=}p(n)+p(k)?$$

Please help me

Comment: The partition function grows very rapidly. (Please see Wikipedia for some details.) There certainly is no simple relationship between $p(n+k)$ or $p(n\cdot k)$ and $p(n)$, $p(k)$.

Comment: And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28number_theory%29) is the Wikipedia articles @André refers to.

Comment: Perhaps the closest thing to what you want is Euler's pentagonal number formula, which is in that wikipedia article: $p(k)=p(k−1)+p(k−2)−p(k−5)−p(k−7)+p(k−12)+p(k−15)−p(k−22)−\dots$, where the numbers $1,2,5,7,12,15\dots$ are the pentagonal numbers $m(3m-1)/2$, $m$ running through the (positive and negative) integers.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly no "rules" for the partition function such as which you speak of. However recently Ken Ono and Jan Bruinier recently [proved a finite formula](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.1182v1.pdf) for computing the partition number.

Also, Folsom, Kent, and Ono show that the partition sequence exhibit [fractal behavior](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/133.pdf).